# Select only direct descendant of body tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<body>
    <div>
      <div class='container'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='container'></div>
</body>
```

How can I get the second `div` named container which is a direct descendant of body with jquery? I should not select it based on no.of the child. I cannot rely on the number of `divs` present in the body.

Comment: If you can't select it based on it's number then why do you describe it based on its number?

Comment: Your question title doesn't match your current code...

Comment: ohh sorry... please check now @Karl-AndréGagnon

Answer (score 3):

Lots of ways, I suppose.  With a limited understanding of constraints, something like:

```
$('body > div.container');
```

Should work

Answer (score 0):

Use '>' in the css selector so you know you're getting the div.container nested directly in the outer div.

```
$('body > div.container')
```

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/p2P2f/1/

Answer (score 0):

**ordered by selector speed:** (for your *specific* DOM example)

```
$(document.body).find('> .container')
```

---

```
$(document.body).find('.container:last')
```

---

```
$('.container:eq(1)')
```

---

```
$('.container:last')
```

---

I didn't sepcifically used `div.container` since it's much slower selector than just `.container`

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<div>
  <div class='container'></div>
</div>
<div class='container second-container'></div>
</body>
```

you can have multiple classes

```
$(".second-container").css();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the order of their appeareance you can do:

```
 $(".container").eq(0);
```

where 0 is the position